# how to extract from multiphylo object based on tree number?

Tags: r

Is there anyway I can pull out a subset of trees from a multiplylo object based on tree numbers?

```
    library(phytools)
    tree_list<- pbtree(b=1, n=100, nsim=50) #create 50 trees
```

Let's say I need to pull out the following trees from tree_list :1,12,26,35

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want another list of trees that only includes select trees like you mentioned, try subsetting with one bracket. You can then rename the trees to match the trees you subsetted.

```
tree_list = tree_list[c(1,12,26,33)]
names(tree_list) = c(1,12,26,33)
tree_list[["12"]]
```

Comment: excellent! how do you subset in a case that we want all trees except those 4?

Comment: Try ```tree_list = tree_list[-4] ```

Comment: I meant all except trees 1,12,26,33

Comment: Oh oh, sorry I misread! ```tree_list = tree_list[-c(1,12,26,33)]``` should work.

Answer (score 3):

To get a sublist from your list, use single brackets `[`

```
tree_list[c(1, 12, 26, 35)]
```

To index the actual object inside a list, use double brackets `[[`

```
tree_list[[1]]
```